# upgrade php failed

Tags: server, apache2, php, xampp

I just upgraded php 7.0 using [this tutorial](https://thishosting.rocks/install-php-on-ubuntu/).

checking the version with php -v:

```
PHP 7.2.9-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Aug 19 2018 07:16:12) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.2.9-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c)  1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Restarted my computer and ... no go:

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.0.8-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...already running.
```

So there is a server running, but I can't find it. What do I need to do to get xampp working again? When I go to localhost I see the Apache2 Debian Default Page. My files are in opt/lampp/htdocs

I understand that I have to use /var/www/ now. Correct? 
How do I start or open phpmyadmin? Or do I have to install that again too?

Comment: You're using a webserver and PHP not installed trough the standard repositories. Either you have to update it as per that systems documentation, or you have to move to use the standard packages in Ubuntu.

Comment: What you did by following the tutorial is that you installed the Ubuntu’s version of [LAMP](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lamp-overview.html.en). Note that the tutorial author used `apt-get install` to upgrade the installed packages but it _installs_ the requested packages if you haven’t installed them before. XAMPP is a different application that got conflicting with your newly installed LAMP. You should uninstall (or disable at least) either LAMP or XAMPP.